# What do the time numbers for WholeStageCodegen mean in Spark SQL View?

Tags: apache-spark

These numbers:

[image: Spark SQL View screenshot]

4.34 h (0 ms, 0 ms, 3.09h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still learning Spark UI but I believe they are "duration (minimum, median, maximum)" with respect to the operation across all the tasks. In your case, I believe they mean one of the tasks for this operation took 3.09 hours, whereas the others took close to 0, and the combination of all the tasks for this operation was 4.34 hours.

I think this means that the data is not partitioned properly and as a result is not distributed evenly across tasks (i.e. skewed partitioning). If you are looking at this operation in the SQL tab, you can click on the Job number at the top, then click on the Stage which includes this WholeStageCodegen operation, and scroll to the bottom to the "Tasks" section and look at the "Shuffle read size/records" for all the tasks. If one is unusually bigger than the others, Spark can't run the tasks in parallel effectively. If this is the case, you may want to look at proper partitioning of your data "perhaps using repartition" or if you are using RDD and not Dataframe, consider using Dataframe which utilizes Spark's optimizer and generates efficient query plans.

These labels may be generated in this code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetrics.scala